# Beginning JavaScript Student Here - Rock, Paper, Scissors (parameter not defined)

Tags: parameters, undefined

This is the Rock, Paper, Scissors problem from CodeAcademy - I like to go over problem sets twice, so on this second go around, I thought I had everything down solid, but apparently do not. Thanks in advance.

```
**ReferenceError: choice1 is not defined**

var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice < 0.67) {
computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
computerChoice = "scissors";
}
var compare = function(choice1,choice2){
if (choice1 === choice2){
return "The result is a tie!";
} 
if (choice1 === "rock"){
if (choice2 === "scissors")
    {
return "Rock wins.";
}
else{
    return "Paper wins.";}
}
if (choice1 === "paper"){
if (choice2 === "rock"){

return "Paper wins.";  

 }else{ 
return "scissors wins."; } 
}
if (choice1 === "scissors"){
if (choice2 === "rock"){
return "rock wins.";
}else 
return "scissors wins.";
}
};  
console.log(compare(choice1, choice2));
```

Answer (score 1):

At the very end of your javascript you call:

```
console.log(compare(choice1, choice2));
```

Those are the incorrect variables. What you actually want is:

```
console.log(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
```

Also, if the user misspells rock, paper or scissors you will get an undefined result from your compare function. You should check the value and re-prompt if it is something unexpected.

Comment: Thank you!! Don't know how I missed that.